# How can I match multiple rows from multiple datasets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP47R.png)

Well, I want to choose the values in blue column(ID) if the values in Yellow Columns match. For example, if agent code in data frame 1 is equal to the agent code in data frame 2 and agent start date in data frame 1 is equal to the start date in data frame 2 and finish date in data frame 1 is equal to the finish date in date frame 2, then chose select or put a color or shade on the value in ID column. Recall that matched rows don't need to be on the same row. I just need to select the rows in data frame 2(the one on the right) if data frame 1(the one on the left) has the same thing.

Comment: I mean, in each data frame, I have 3 columns. I need to select the rows which is in the data frame 1 and has same other 2 columns with the other row in the data frame 2.

Comment: Rather put self-explanatory examples of your data and show the sample rows which would match and how will it be presented in the worksheet.. Will be helpful to the people answering your questions.

Comment: And include your attempts and research.

Comment: Added. If you need more specifications, let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

For experimental purpose i use Sheet1 so make and changes regarding sheet name if needed and try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LR As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LR

            If (.Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("K" & i).Value) And (.Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value) And (.Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value) Then
                .Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```